# Upstart fills up with gigabytes of "QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Cannot make invalid context current"

Tags: linux-mint, logs, upstart

I use XFCE on Linux Mint 18.2.

Apparently, my `/sbin/upstart --user` process is filling my`~/.cache/upstart/startxfce4.log` with gobs and gobs of:

```
QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Cannot make invalid context current.
```

Why would it be doing that and how can I make it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

- It's not `upstart`. The *process* which writes to that log may be upstart, but it's getting the messages from elsewhere.
- It's not even `startxfce4`, nor xfce4-session (which is run by startxfce4) - it's a specific app that's spamming the log.
- Since you're  getting constant spam, if you kill the app the log will stop increasing in size. So, kill your apps one by one (start with what seems to be using Qt, since `QGLContext` is a Qt class), until the log stops growing.

... after doing that on my system, it turned out the culprit was `amarok`. Not that I know *why* it does that, but that's a subject for another question.